# Insert comma into string at the place you want

Tags: json, regex, linux, sed

I'm trying to extract the balance from this string (which I did already) and add a comma to the string like 6841,12691421 (already done that also) BUT! theres a problem with doing it the way I did.

```json
{
    "address": "NKNXyCmatuYuAnMFufdDnLL82qmvgB4uAYt6",
    "count_transactions": 59606,
    "first_transaction": "2020-08-07 17:25:51",
    "last_transaction": "2021-05-02 09:09:24",
    "balance": 684112691421,
    "name": []
}
```

I did it with (excuse the noob code):

```sh
sed -n -r 's/(^.*balance":)([^"]+)".*/\2/p' | sed -e 's/[",]//g' | sed 's/./&,/4'
```

**The problem:**

The `sed 's/./&,/4'` is a static thing. When the balance is lower by one character the output is wrong then, example `68411269142 the balance should be 684,11269142.

I need a solution to count the comm`a insert place from the right, 8 characters in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this single `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/(^.*balance":)([^",]+).*/\2/; s/[0-9]{8}$/,&/' file

6841,12691421
```

- `s/[0-9]{8}$/,&/` matches 8 trailing digits and inserts a comma before it

Answer (score 2):

Two jq-only solutions:

a) without any regex overhead:

```
jq -r '.balance | tostring | .[:-8]+ ","+ .[-8:]'
```

b) with regex:

```
jq -r 'tostring|sub("(?<tail>[0-9]{8}$)"; ",\(.tail)" )'
```

#### Caveat

Unfortunately these jq-only solutions will only work reliably for integers with fewer than 16 digits unless you have a sufficiently recent version of jq (after 1.6).

Answer (score 1):

With `jq` and `sed`:

```
jq '.balance' file.json | sed -E 's/.{8}$/,&/'
```

Output:

```
6841,12691421
```